# I want to make two separate function one to connect to azure storage and create table using Python below is what I am trying to do

Tags: python, azure-table-storage

I am new to coding. I want to make two functions to be used one is to create connection to storage table and one is to create a table in storage.
Have created a function connecToStorage which will connect to storage

```
def connecToStorage(accname, acckey,connstr):
                table_service = TableService(account_name=accname,
                                             account_key=acckey)
                table_service = TableService(connection_string=connstr)
                return table_service
```

Now I want to access the table_service object to create a table in the storage I connected to. how to do that? I am trying below but its not correct.

```
def create_tabel(tablename):
            connecToStorage.create_table(tablename)
```

Comment: "I am doing something wrong" is not a problem specification.  The immediate problem I see is that you wrote `connectToStorage` to *require* three arguments, but called it with only one.  You *must* give it *exactly* the arguments you promised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for this and found a solution that i can use constructor for doing this. i can create a constructor using

```
def __init__(self, accname, connstr):
    self.table_service = TableService(account_name=accname,account_key=acckey)
```

and after it i can create table like:

```
def create_tabel(tablename):
      slef.table_service.create_table(tablename)
```